# Android ActionBar Menupoint ( with 3 Dots)

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I wanted to implement the ActionBar (Android 4.0) in a test App to see how it works etc.

My question: Almost every App for 4.0 have on the right corner of the ActionBar a "menuButton" with a Icon that shows 3 vertical Dots. 
(See: http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ICS-Screen05.jpg)

How can I implement this on my App?

I tried to implement this "menuButton" with ah Spinneradapter.. but this one always displays after the App Name in the ActionBar.

Btw. Another question: 
I have a refresh button in my App.. how can i make the "Refresh-Icon" spin, whenever its clicked?

Here is my Code...

Thanks for the Help, and please excuse my programming skills... i am a newbie! :)

```
public class IVOAppActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, null);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


/** Create ActionBar */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menubar, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Handle clicks on ActionBar */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fake Refreshing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /*final Intent i = new Intent(this, Help.class);
    startActivity(i);*/
    break;
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /*final Intent ii = new Intent(this, Options.class);
    startActivity(ii);*/
    break;


} return false;}}
```

---

XML ActionBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_popup_sync_1"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:showAsAction="always"/></menu>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I implement this on my App?

Have an options menu, with items that are not hoisted into the action bar as toolbar buttons and the like. Since you elected to make your own two options menu items have `android::showAsAction="always"`, they will be toolbar buttons, leaving you with nothing for the spillover menu.

Note that you will only see the three-dots button on devices that lack an off-screen MENU button.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I didn't know that only a few Devices can see that "MenuButton"...

In this case how can I (for example the "settings" Button) make, that it displays a DropdownMenu when i click it? I want the same behavior like the "Menu" Button with the 3 Dots... Can you give me an example or something?

Thank you anyways :)

Comment: @HardStyle: You are welcome to display a `ListPopupView`. I have not tried doing this manually from an action bar toolbar button.